# Angular 15 filter component based on generic type and inner properties

Tags: angular, typescript

In angular 15 I have a dynamic select component with filtering option.

I would like to enable extra predicate based on type and more specifically a list of key from this unknown type and be able to filter on this inner properties also.

I have a generic component that can trigger a filter function based on a boolean input (withFilter) that will show a search component above the list of option implemented.

This filter will only have the options values as predicate to reduce the list of object given

for example :

```js
interface Car { 
  name: string;
  id: string;
  constructor: string;
}
```

Here the filter will only filter on car.name

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'ng-select',
  template: `
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    <div class="ng-listbox-filter" *ngIf="withFilter">
      <ng-listbox-filter></ng-listbox-filter> // add inputs to filterComponent ? How ?
    </div>
`,
})
export class SelectComponent<T = unknown, P extends Extract<keyof T, string>>{
  @Input() withFilter?: boolean = false;
  @Input() extraPredicates?: T;
  @Input() extraPredicatesProperties?: P[];
}
```

Then I would pass the interface given to selectComponent in extraPredicate and the array of keys I want to filter on with extraPredicateProperty to filterComponent (at least that's my idea for now). On this example i would like to filter also on id and constructor let's say (even if only the names would be filtered)